# Combinatorial design to compress a Boolean lattice without confusing small sets

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

Is there a kind of combinatorial design that controls the sizes of small unions of the blocks?

I'm looking for a set $B$ of $|B|=b$ blocks, where $b\sim100$, which are subsets of a set $X$ of $|X|=v$ points, $v=32$ or less preferably, $v=64$. The blocks don't need to have a uniform size, but they should all be nonempty. More generally, given a union of a "small" set of blocks, it should be possible to infer the number of blocks in the union. To be precise, there should be an integer $\ell\geq 2$, ideally as large as possible, such that $B$ has the following property:

- If $P$ and $Q$ are subsets of $B$ with $|P|<|Q|\leq \ell$, then $\left|\bigcup P\right|<\left|\bigcup Q\right|$.

Note that if $b\leq v$ then this would be trivial. Just let $B$ be a set of $b$ distinct singleton subsets of $X$. Then for all $P\subset B$ we get $\left|\bigcup P\right|=|P|$, so the highlighted property is guaranteed for all $\ell$.

So the whole point of this question is asking if we can achieve some compression, i.e. $b>v$. Note that in the $b>v$ regime we can't possibly achieve $\ell=b$ anymore, but I'd still like for $\ell$ to be large.

For example, perhaps there is a design with $b=128$, $v=32$, and $\ell=3$, such that every block has size $4$, every union of two blocks has size $6$, $7$, or $8$, and every union of three blocks has size $9$ or more.

Arguments that limit $\ell$ or construct nice designs would be helpful. References to what these things are called would also be helpful!

---

Edit: According to [https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/Andw.html](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/Andw.html) we have these nice constant-weight binary codes to work with:

- $A(64, 6, 4) = 336$ [citing](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/Andw.html#d6) Brouwer et al (1990) "[A new table of constant weight codes](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/59932)"
- $A(64, 8, 5) = 192$ [citing](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/Andw.html#d8) a Steiner system $S(2,5,65)$. (How does that work?)
- $A(63, 10, 6) = 126 $ [citing](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/Andw.html#d10) Smith et al (2006) "[A New Table of Constant Weight Codes of Length Greater than 28](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v13i1a2)" who list it on page 12, Table 7, bottom row as "CC" meaning a construction from a cyclic permutation

These constructions give us blocks that intersect each other at at most one point. From that, we can achieve $\ell=3$. In fact, the last construction of weight $6$ *almost* gets us to $\ell=4$:

1. Each block has weight $6$.
2. A union of two blocks has weight $11$ or $12$.
3. A union of three blocks has weight $15$ to $18$.
4. A union of four blocks has weight $18$ to $24$.

If there were some argument why a union of four blocks could be forced to have weight $\geq 19$, then we'd get $\ell=4$ after all.

Given those results, my questions are, more specifically:

- Are these sorts of codes the best bet for satisfying the inequality that I want?
- Is there a way to get to $\ell=4$ with $b\geq100$ and $v\leq64$?
- Is there a literature on this question that I've missed?

Comment: For any $r\geq 2$, if you take $B$ to consist of all subsets of $X$ of cardinality $r$, then $(X,B)$ satisfies your conditions with $l=2$, and $b=\binom{v}{r}$ is much larger than $v$, which gives us hope. It is however, unclear to me at this point if there are examples with $l=3,b \gt v$ and arbitrarily large $v$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy That helps! With that $B$, we get $\ell=2$ from inclusion-exclusion on any union of two blocks. To continue in that direction, we could try looking for a binary nonlinear error correcting code $(n=v, M=b, d)$ with a large enough minimum Hamming distance $d$, such that we can get the desired inequality for $\ell=3$ from inclusion-exclusion again. At least, that seems like it's not obviously impossible. I'm a bit out of my depth, though, in that I don't know what sorts of bounds apply to such codes.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy FYI I edited the question with some $\ell=3$ examples. I don't know about arbitrarily large $v$, though. (Personally I'm not so interested in $v>64$, since I have an application in mind where I want to use machine arithmetic.)

Comment: (Since you said $v=32$ was of the most interest to you) With a "brute-force" search algorithm, I found a configuration with $v=32$, $l=3$ and $b=66$. I know this is far from the $b=100$ you wished for, but my computer didn't like going further than that..